# Drag drop a usercontrol in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, user-controls, drag-and-drop

I have, what should be , a very simple problem, but now I have used 5 hours without results. 
I have a usercontrol, UserControl1, which I want to drag and drop on my form, Form1.

That’s it. It should be simple, but I have googled for hours without results. Does anybody have a sample code to fix this?

Comment: User controls you create in your project are added to the toolbox.  Provided the AutoToolboxPopulate option in Tools + Options is set to true.  My crystal ball says it can't see your screen from here.

Comment: Drag and drop starting on the same form, or a different form? Design-time or run-time?

Answer (score 1):

I dont know what a user control is (I'm still learning) but I found something that might help.
In this code, add two TextBox controls to a form and set the AllowDrop property of the second TextBox control to True. 
Then use this code to enable drag and drop

```
Private MouseIsDown As Boolean = False

Private Sub TextBox1_MouseDown(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As _
System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs) Handles TextBox1.MouseDown
    ' Set a flag to show that the mouse is down.
    MouseIsDown = True
End Sub

Private Sub TextBox1_MouseMove(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As _
System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs) Handles TextBox1.MouseMove
    If MouseIsDown Then
        ' Initiate dragging.
        TextBox1.DoDragDrop(TextBox1.Text, DragDropEffects.Copy)
    End If
    MouseIsDown = False
End Sub

Private Sub TextBox2_DragEnter(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As _
System.Windows.Forms.DragEventArgs) Handles TextBox2.DragEnter
    ' Check the format of the data being dropped.
    If (e.Data.GetDataPresent(DataFormats.Text)) Then
        ' Display the copy cursor.
        e.Effect = DragDropEffects.Copy
    Else
        ' Display the no-drop cursor.
        e.Effect = DragDropEffects.None
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub TextBox2_DragDrop(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As _
System.Windows.Forms.DragEventArgs) Handles TextBox2.DragDrop
    ' Paste the text.
    TextBox2.Text = e.Data.GetData(DataFormats.Text)
End Sub
```

I hope that you can use this for a usercontrol. Good luck and comment!

Comment: Thanks, Ill try that. I also found another way. I post it below. But first of all. A usercontrol could be anything, that you want tu use more than once. Example: Say you want a special kind of button, that, when you press it, it says "hi". Say you want to use that button more than once. Then you could create the button in a usercontrol, and just call that control each time you need it. Result is that you need only a few lines of code each time you call the button in your main script.

Comment: Thanks for letting me now that. And the code looks great. Just a question, could you mark the most convenient answer. It's how we earn reputation here at Stack Overflow. Again, thanks for letting me know about usercontrol. That could help me with my OWN code. :)

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code, I have used, to get it work. 
Now I have a form, Form1, and a usercontrol, Usercontrol1. To drag the usercontrol, I inserted a panel in the top of the usercontrol, and only if the user pressed the panel (panel1), the control should to move - like normal windows forms.

```
Public Class UserControl1
Shared mypositionX As Integer
Shared mypositionY As Integer
Shared mBlnFormDragging As Boolean

Shared drawBeginX As Integer
Shared drawBeginY As Integer

Shared drawing As Boolean

Private Sub Panel1_MouseMove(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs) Handles Panel1.MouseMove
    If mBlnFormDragging = True Then
        Dim position As Point = Form1.PointToClient(MousePosition)
        Me.Location = New Point(position)
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub Panel1_MouseUp(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs) Handles Panel1.MouseUp
    '        Dim dd1 As DragDropEffects = DoDragDrop(ParentForm, DragDropEffects.Move)
    mBlnFormDragging = False
    Dim position As Point = Form1.PointToClient(MousePosition)
    Location = New Point(position)
End Sub

Public Sub Panel1_MouseDown(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs) Handles Panel1.MouseDown
    'Dim dd1 As DragDropEffects = DoDragDrop(ParentForm, DragDropEffects.Move)
    mBlnFormDragging = True
End Sub
```